# Windows 10 Folder Search Sucks

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search

when i do a search in a windows 10 folder using file explorer and the box at the top right, I get a list of matching files and folders.

All well and good, but if I open up one of those folders and find it doesn't have what I'm looking for - and then go back to the search results, windows 10 does the search all over again!

This is ludicrous. Is there some way to fix this so that windows just goes back to already-done search list?

Comment: I bet 99.9999% of people agree with you on this one. It is not only that, you click a folder and then the stupid search results bar remains, so you have no clue where that folder is, you go back, and try again. Ridonculous. Totally. Absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. Windows assumes that things might have changed and therefore searches again.
A workaround is to right-click the match, and chose 'open in new window'. Then, you can simply close that new window, and be back to the screen you had.